# How to verify the Sitecore Robot detection feature?

Tags: sitecore-forms

Are there any scripts/tools to verify the Sitecore Robot detection feature in Sitecore Forms?

If yes, please share some tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if robots detection works at all, you can execute the following steps:

- install an extension like https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=pl&pli=1 to be able to modify your browser user agent
- switch to user agent to use googlebot name (you may need to add it with e.g.`Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) Chrome/W.X.Y.Z Safari/537.36` value)
- clear all the cookies from your website
- open `view-source:https://your.website.com` to see the source of your website (without opening your website first).
- if robots detection works, you will **not** see visitor identification javascript in the source:

```xml
<script type="text/javascript" src="/layouts/system/VisitorIdentification.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Marek. Is this same applicable to Sitecore forms?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer/reference based on the recent comment.**

To use robot detection with forms, you must install and enable `xDB and xDB tracking`. Robot detection must also be enabled, which is by default.

If you are using a tool (such as DevTools or Fiddler) to resubmit a form (that is, to resend the request), the tracker treats all requests the same way. This means, for example, that if the original form submitted was treated as human, when the form is resubmitted it will also be treated as human.

Reference : https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/103/sitecore-experience-platform/work-with-robot-detection-for-forms.html

Hope it helps!